# How can I determine which checkbox was selected in your state?

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, state, react-native-elements

I'm using [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html) checkbox, i have 2 checkboxes and i want to select one of them only and i managed to do that, but I'm trying to console.log the checked box only but it's not working because they have two different states, so how can i determine which box was checked in my app using the state? here is the code:

**Initial state:**

```
state: {
  single: false,
  married: false
}
```

**Checkboxes:**

```
 <CheckBox title="Single"
              checked={this.state.single}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ single: !this.state.single, 
              married: false})}/>

 <CheckBox title="Married"
              checked={this.state.married}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ married: !this.state.married, 
              single: false})}/>
```

I have an api and i want to post data in it, it has `maritalStatus` attribute and i want to send either married or single as a string value based on the checked box

Comment: You have the state for both single and married. The one which is selected will be true. So you already know which checkbox is selected.

Comment: @HemantParashar okay, but if i want to send the true inside a post call how can i do that?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question and provide some more info on what is that you actually wanna achieve and provide code related to that. This is all so vague right now.

Comment: @Andrew console.log(this.state.married) or console.log(this.state.single), they return true or false according to the checked one, but the thing is i only want the true value only without using the 2 states

Comment: @Andrew that's my point i can't figure out how to check

Comment: Update your question with how you will use the result

Comment: @Andrew updated

Comment: What type of variable is `marriedStatus`? Boolean? String?

Comment: @Andrew updated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really three conditions that exist.

1. The user hasn’t selected a box
2. The user selects single
3. The user selects married.

If you have validation, meaning that the user must check a box then you can discount the first condition. From that it is then possible to tell, once a user has selected a box, what their choice was by knowing the state of only one of the boxes. So if you have a button that checks validation you could do something like this.

```
<Button 
  title={'check married status'}
  onPress={() => {
   if (!this.state.single && !this.state.married) {
     alert('Please check a box)
   } else {
     // we only need to check one of them
     let marriedStatus = this.state.married ? 'married' : 'single';
     alert(`You are ${marriedStatus}`)
     // then you can do what you want with the marriedStatus here
   }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are xor operation. You'll need to set the current state of everyone by looking the past state of the clicked button.

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html

single:

```
{single: !this.state.single, married: this.state.single}
```

married

```
{single:this.state.married, married: !this.state.married}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to manage two states for this. A person can either married or single in this case.
So you need to do something like this

If you wanna have both the checkbox as unchecked on load then

```
state: {
  single: void 0,
}


<CheckBox title="Single"
              checked={this.state.single}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ single: !this.state.single})}/>

 <CheckBox title="Married"
              checked={this.state.single !== undefined && !this.state.single}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ married: !this.state.single})}/>
```

or if one checked then

```
state: {
  single: true,
}


<CheckBox title="Single"
              checked={this.state.single}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ single: !this.state.single})}/>

 <CheckBox title="Married"
              checked={!this.state.single}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ married: !this.state.single})}/>
```

Hope this works for you. :)